# Show image in text field

Tags: ios, swift

I have added button in accessory view of text field.
On click of this button i want show the image/icon in text of text field.

How can i do this?

I tried this :

```
let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self.text ?? "") 
let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment(   image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "dummyUser")    
let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)   
fullString.append(image1String) 
self.attributedText = fullString
```

Comment: Hi, can you add a screenshot of the exact thing you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to add custom button in keyboard for a text field. When user click on  this button then in text of the text field image (custom emoji) should be added.

Comment: @sajwan emojis are Unicode chars...

Comment: @Jean Baptiste Is it possible what i want to achieve with image icon